# Hydrogen Atom in two spatial dimensions with $1/r$ potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

I am almost new to Quantum Mechanics. Recently I learned about the hydrogen atom in three dimensions. I struggle to answer the following exercise where the hydrogen atom in two dimensions is considered:

> For an hydrogen atom the stationary Schroedinger Equation in polar coordinates is given by
> \begin{align}
> \left[ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\right) - \frac{\alpha\hbar c}{r} - E \right]\psi(r,\phi) = 0.
> \end{align}
> The wave function of the ground state of the hydrogen atom in two dimensions has the form $\psi_0(r, \phi) = N_0\exp(-\nu_0r/a_B)$, where $a_B$ denotes the Bohr radius $a_B = \hbar / (mc\alpha)$.
>
>
> I am asked to compute $\nu_0$, the ground state energy $E_0$ as well as $N_0 > 0$.

While I think that computing the constant $N_0$ as well as the energy $E_0$ is easy, I struggle to see how one can compute $\nu_0$. Can anyone help?

**Edit**:

We find

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\psi_0(r, \phi) &= 0, \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\psi_0(r, \phi)  &= -\frac{\nu_0}{a_B}\psi_0(r,\phi), \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}\psi_0(r, \phi)  &= \frac{\nu_0^2}{a_B^2}\psi_0(r,\phi).
\end{align}

Plugging the results in yields

\begin{align}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\nu_0^2}{a_B^2}\psi_0(r,\phi) + \frac{\hbar^2 \nu_0}{2mra_B}\psi_0(r,\phi) - \frac{\alpha\hbar c}{r}\psi_0(r,\phi) = E_0\psi_0(r,\phi) 
\end{align}
or equivalently
\begin{align}
E_0 = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\nu_0^2}{a_B^2} + \frac{\hbar^2 \nu_0}{2mra_B} - \frac{\alpha\hbar c}{r}.
\end{align}
Due to
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} N_0^2 \exp(-2\nu_0r/a_B) \ \mathrm{d}r = \frac{a_B\cdot N_0^2}{2\nu_0} \overset{!}{=} 1,
\end{align}
we find
\begin{align}
N_0 = \sqrt{\frac{2\nu_0}{a_B}}.
\end{align}

At this point I do think that once having $\nu_0$ the computation of $E_0$ and $N_0$ can be finished.

Comment: You compute it by determining what the value has to be to satisfy the equation. If you know how to get $E$, you should have shown that work.

Comment: @G.Smith I improved the question.

Comment: How can $E_0$ depend on $r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:  the $E$ that appears in Schrödinger's equation is the energy for the "entire state".  In particular, it's just a number, and cannot be a function of $r$.  So looking at your equation for $E_0$, what must be true about the parameters in it to make it independent of $r$?

(Also, your equation for $E_0$ is incorrect due to an algebra error.  You'll need to correct this to get the correct answer.  Note that $\nu_0$ should end up being a dimensionless number.)

Comment: In this case we have $\nu_0 = a_B\alpha \hbar c$. That was a good hint! Thank you!

Comment: No. Can you see that $\nu_0$ must be a dimensionless number?

Comment: Right. It should be $\nu_0 = \frac{2m a_B \alpha \hbar c}{\hbar^2} = 2$.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.